# Modifying JSON Body in Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have the following flow:

Request -> 1) Validate JSON Body -> 2) Validate JSON for Security Concerns -> ...etc

And Throw exceptions / give appropriate JSON Responses in 1) or 2).

I have tried to use Interceptors and Filters.

Filters: I can modify the body by having a Request Wrapper and then passing it along the chain to the JSON Validation, however when I throw exceptions they are not intercepted by the @ControllerAdvice Exception Handler, which works for everything else. From what I have read this is by design...? Also I have tried to set a response manually, example below, but it seems spring boot changes the status code to 405.

```
response.getWriter().write("{\"test\" : \"test\"");
response.sendError(400);
```

Interceptors: I get an error because I am reading the body more than once, I can not see how to set the Custom HttpServletRequestWrapper I have made **before** the interceptors run.

I am after a way of implementing this scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realised that because Filters are run first I can modify the request by using a Request Wrapper. Then I use an interceptor to run the security and json checks.

I would still like to know how to modify responses in a Filter though, I do not like how spring boot will change it even though you already have a response code.